# Is the id type in Objective-C truly dynamic

Tags: objective-c

Is the id type truly dynamic (late binding at runtime) or analogous to the 'var' keyword in C# (late binding at compile time)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW33):

> id is defined as pointer to an object data structure:

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

and more importantly

> The id type is completely nonrestrictive. By itself, it yields no information about an object, except that it is an object. At some point, a program typically needs to find more specific information about the objects it contains. Since the id type designator can’t supply this information to the compiler, each object has to be able to supply it at runtime.
>
> The isa instance variable identifies the object’s class—what kind of object it is. Objects with the same behavior (methods) and the same kinds of data (instance variables) are members of the same class.
>
> **Objects are thus dynamically typed at runtime.** Whenever it needs to, the runtime system can find the exact class that an object belongs to, just by asking the object. (To learn more about the runtime, see Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide.) Dynamic typing in Objective-C serves as the foundation for dynamic binding, discussed later.

Answer (score 6):

Truly dynamic. There isn't even any static type-checking done on it (unless you declare protocol list for the variable). It's defined merely as a pointer to an object. For example, you can do this:

```
Class classes[3];
classes[0] = [NSMutableString class];
classes[1] = [NSMutableArray class];
classes[2] = [NSMutableData class];
srandom(time(NULL));
id foo = [[classes[random % 3] alloc] init];
NSLog(@"It is a %@", [foo class]);
```